# SVN comments for cpp files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am working on a project regarding svn,is there any way to force svn comments or log messages only for cpp files....thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use a subversion pre-commit hook. Here are a few examples that require comments, it should be simple enough to modify them to work only when a cpp file is involved.

http://www.anujgakhar.com/2008/02/14/how-to-force-comments-on-svn-commit/
http://www.stillnetstudios.com/require-subversion-comments-minimum/

Comment: I have tried using grep and find commands...still its ideal, forcing commands for all kind of files

Comment: could u tell the steps to modify it for cpp files

Answer (score 1):

It is ideal to provide a commit message for any commit you are doing.

Anyway, you can setup a client side pre-commit hook using TortoiseSVN to see if the message is empty and if the file is a cpp file, you can block the commit.

If you want this to be done for everyone and can't ask everyone to setup client side hooks, you can setup a server side pre-commit hook to do the same. Note that TortoiseSVN client side commit hooks are very different from server side hooks.